# Java reactor `suscribe` is sometime blocking, sometime not

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have been playing around for some time with reactor, but I still need to get something.

This piece of code

```java
    Flux.range(1, 1000)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofNanos(1))
        .map(integer -> integer + 1)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("after");
```

Returns:

```bash
after
2
3
4
```

which is expected as the documentation of subscribe states: `this will immediately return control to the calling thread.`

Why, then, this piece of code:

```java
    Flux.range(1, 1000)
        .map(integer -> integer + 1)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

returns

```bash
1
2
...
1000
1001
after
```

I can never figure out when `subscribe` will block or not, and that's very annoying when writing batches.

If anyone has the answer, that would be amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no blocking code in your snippet.

In first example you use `.delayElements()` and it switches the executing to another thread and releases your main thread. So you can see your `System.out.println("after");` executing in Main thread immediately, whilst the reactive chain is being executed on `parallel-n` threads.

Your first example:

```
18:49:29.195 [main] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - AFTER
18:49:29.199 [parallel-1] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 2
18:49:29.201 [parallel-2] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 3
18:49:29.202 [parallel-3] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 4
18:49:29.203 [parallel-4] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 5
18:49:29.205 [parallel-5] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 6
```

But your second example does not switch the executing thread, so your reactive chain executes on Main thread. And after it completes it continues to execute your `System.out.println("after");`

```
18:51:28.490 [main] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 995
18:51:28.490 [main] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 996
18:51:28.490 [main] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 997
18:51:28.490 [main] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 998
18:51:28.490 [main] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 999
18:51:28.490 [main] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 1000
18:51:28.490 [main] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - v: 1001
18:51:28.491 [main] INFO com.example.demo.FluxTest - AFTER
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to switch the thread in your second snippet, basically you have two options:

1. Add `subscribeOn(<Scheduler>)` in any place of your reactive chain. Then the whole subscription process will happen on a thread from scheduler you provided.
2. Add `publishOn(<Scheduler>)`, for example, after `Flux.range()`, then the emitting itself will happen on your calling thread, but the downstream will be executed on a thread from the scheduler you provided

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And would you know how I can make the first snippet executing in the main thread ? with a `suscribeOn()` maybe ?

Comment: you cannot back to the main thread in first snippet, this is just how delayElements works. Updated the answer about thread switching in the second snippet