# why the below code is blocking in project reactor

Tags: java, asynchronous, project-reactor, reactive

I am quite new to reactive programming. I understood that it won't block the code for large data retrieval. To state that, I wrote the below code.

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class ProjectReactorExamples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("started " +Thread.currentThread().getName());       
        Flux.range(1,10).subscribe(data -> print(data));
        System.out.println("Finished");
      }
    
    private static void print(long data) {      
        System.out.println("Printing "+data+ "with the thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());     
    }
}
```

In the below code I was expecting the output as

```
"Started"
"Finished"
"print 1 -10 " //printing 1-10
```

But I am always getting the output in a sequential manner which means the 'Finished ..' output is always showing after subscribe is completed. Here I can see a blocking. How do I rewrite this in order to see 'Finished' as second and subscribed data as last.

Comment: The threading model is a little complex. Does [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75127969/2678097) answers your question ?

Comment: take a look to the similar question and my answer. In short, there's no blocking code in your snippet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75071304/java-reactor-suscribe-is-sometime-blocking-sometime-not/75071744#75071744

Comment: Thanks @kerbermeister.
In the real world, I have to load tons of data(from DB/web service) while the application starts up.
This causes the application for a slow startup. My intention was to let this code run in the background without affecting the startup and cache it.
I will use those data later in my program. I don't want to load the data once the application has started. I was under the assumption
that I don't have to use any background thread or a separate process to load the data.
This will be handled by an asynchronous framework.